# Can I list all users assigned to one or more user stories that are related to a specific feature in Rally?

Tags: rally

I am trying to create a kanban board or custom grid that will show the following:

- Features tagged with "tag name"
- All users assigned to any user stories/tasks linked to the feature

I see that you can list all artifacts with the (Tags.Name contains [yourtagnamehere]) in order to get all of the initiatives/features/etc. with their corresponding stories, but is there a way to look into the actual owners of those stories to generate a list of team members"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality exists in the API via the Collaborators field on PortfolioItem, but for some reason the Collaborators field was never really exposed correctly on boards/grids.

I forked the Custom List app and added support for the Collaborators field.  You can copy/paste this into a Custom HTML app and give it a spin:

https://github.com/krmorse/CollaboratorsCustomListApp/blob/master/deploy/App-uncompressed.html